# How do puppet components cooperate with each other?

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

I am using Puppet open source edition.

I found there are several components in Puppet 3.7.5:

- Puppet-master
- Puppet-agent
- MCollective
- Hiera
- PuppetDB

But I don't know how they cooperate with each other. I have seen a simple architecture which only includes the puppet-master and puppet-agent.

As for other components, I don't know how they are cooperated. Can anyone give me a detail information about how they cooperate or any data flow graph?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Full disclosure I work at PuppetLabs!**

A basic breakdown of the pieces:

- Puppet-agent

The Puppet agent on each node sends facts about the node's configuration — detailing the hardware, operating system, package versions and other information — to the Puppet master. Basically this will kick off a Puppet run every `n` minutes (30 by default), then report the changes to the master.

- Puppet-master

The Puppet master uses facts provided by the agents to compile detailed data about how each node should be configured — called the catalog — and sends it back to the Puppet agent.

- MCollective

MCollective is an orchestration tool for Puppet, mainly used to programmatically execute actions on clusters of servers. Think Fabric, Capistrano etc. but a lot higher level.
[More detail here](https://puppetlabs.com/mcollective)

- Hiera

Hiera is a **hierarchical** key/value store for Puppet. It allows you to enable a separation of concerns by keeping data in Hiera and code in puppet.
[More detail here](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/puppet.html)

- PuppetDB

PuppetDB is a data-warehouse that caches data generated by Puppet, and allows you to leverage that data with an API.

Here's a diagram on how they all fit together in the Enterprise edition:
[image: Puppet Architecture Diagram]

The OSS won't have the console, but most of the rest of it applies to the OSS edition too. Read more [here](https://docs.puppet.com/pe/2015.3/install_system_requirements.html#firewall-configuration).

For further questions, there's tons of [documentation](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/), [IRC rooms](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/Irc_Channel) and learning [materials](https://puppetlabs.com/learn).